# SSLHandshakeException when calling Firebase Cloud Function via HTTP Request

Tags: android, firebase, android-networking, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a Firebase Cloud function from my Android app, but I keep getting the following error: javax.net.ssl.HandshakeException: Connection closed by peer.

The function I am trying to call is one the sample functions called "addMessage" in Firebase's Get Started Guide (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). I am using HttpURLConnection in an AsyncTask to make the HTTP request, and the code I am using is as follows:

```
private class requestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String temp =  "https://us-central1-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage";
            URL url = new URL(temp);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

After looking around, it seems like the only solution is to create my own TrustManager, but I don't know how to obtain the CA from Firebase for this specific scenario. If someone can point me in the right direction, or perhaps to an easier solution, that would be greatly appreciated.